# Disable highlighting in an HTML SELECT box

Tags: css, html-select

I have a select box, `<select multiple=true`, that the user populates with values via a Picklist mechanism. I would like to disable highlighting in this box because, by definition, the values in this box *are* the selection.

Just to clarify, I am NOT referring to text selection, which is what `::selection` operates on. I'm talking about the usually blue highlighting that the browser applies to selected line item(s) when the user clicks on them.

I'm not worried about the user blindly clicking around, because I am auto-selecting all items onsubmit so that all the values get sent.

Comment: Ohh that hurts my head. Can you rephrase it a little or include a screen shot, I'm struggling to understand what you want or how you are actually using the select box.

Comment: A Picklist is that UI mechanism where items are selected from a list/tree, (usually on the left), by copying/moving them to an accumulator list, (usually on the right), by dragging or by clicking arrows. My question concerns the accumulator list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just list the items in their own div instead of a select element? You aren't having the users interact with them anyway, right?

Then, you can have a select element w/ all the values you want, but make it hidden via CSS so that the user won't ever see them. It'll just be there in  your form so that you can grab those values on your submit.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading you correctly, it sounds like you're using an accumulator model where you have a "source" box (or list or select or something) and a "selected" box. Rather than accumulating into a [select], maybe use a div? If you must use a select, you could try disabling it, but that carries other visual baggage. You could also try styling the select color, but that's definitely not going to be cross-browser.

Comment: Concur, disabling carries other visual baggage. So styling the select color is what I guess I'm looking to do. But how?

Comment: here's one page that outlines it: http://home.tiscali.nl/developerscorner/fdc-varia/styling-dropdown-boxes.htm

I don't think you can do it in a way that will work in every browser, though. I'd go with the div approach.

Answer (score 0):

Make it disabled?

`<select disabled="disabled">`

This would gray it out, unfortunately- the other option might be some javascript to unselect any selections.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, the user does not actually selects the items? then why not either disable it or if customer still interacts with it, you might need to go with some JS code to help yourself